# Why are files in the directory /sys/class missing when Ubuntu 22.04 is set up on the virtual machine VMware 17 Pro?

Tags: 22.04, vmware

When I tried to get the power of my PC's power supply, I found that I could not find the `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` directory, there was only the ACDA directory under `/sys/class/power_supply`. Is this a problem that occurs when Ubuntu is running under a virtual machine, or did I encounter some error that caused the file to be missing?

[image]

Comment: Is the VM actually configured to [Report Battery Information in the Guest](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Linux/17.0/com.vmware.player.linux.using.doc/GUID-489559B5-7C16-4C05-94BC-890AA7353A0E.html) ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which solved my problem!